# Laravel Routing Route::resource inside Route::group

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new in `Laravel`. 
routes/api.php I have written this function

```
   Route::group(['namespace' => "Catalogue"],function(){
    Route::resource('product','Product');
});
```

I have created a resource controller:

```
app/Controllers/Catalogue/Product.php
```

This is my index method:

```
public function index()
    {
        $pdo = DB::select('select count(*) from offers');
        return $pdo;
    }
```

I am trying to get the result from index method from url:

http://localhost:8000/api/Catalogue/product

However, this results in `404 not found`. 
Note: There is no issue in this part of url `http://localhost:8000/api`

Comment: `Route groups allow you to share route attributes, such as middleware or namespaces, across a large number of routes without needing to define those attributes on each individual route. ` -- Is `product` is middleware or namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your route the link generated is http://localhost:8000/api/product

If you need the link to be http://localhost:8000/api/Catalogue/product , then add the prefix to the group.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'Catalogue', 'namespace' => 'Catalogue'], function() {
    Route::resource('product', 'Product');
});
```

The `namespace` only sets the default namespace for the controller. The `prefix` sets the route prefix for all the routes in the group.

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting the wrong uri.
Check `http://localhost:8000/api/product`

The namespace in the group route means you are assigning a namespace to a group of controllers. As you can see here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-group-namespaces. It has nothing to do with the routes.

Here you can see the other routes when you make them in the controller.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#controllers-and-namespaces

Comment: Thanks , but can you please tell me if my URI will be like: http://localhost:8000/api/Catalogue/Product, http://localhost:8000/api/Catalogue/Brand and so on, i.e inside Catalogue, how should I group them then.